# Rails generates wrong asset urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline

rails beginner here

I am trying to set an app to production but having big issues with the asset pipeline. Under development every asset is generated under `/assets/blabla.extension`

However, I am running nginx and when running rake assets:precompile it creates assets under `/public/assets` as it should. But when I visit my app it generates urls like `/application.css` and not `/assets/application-digestq12343.css` as it should.

I think there is an easy fix to this problem.. but I cannot find it. Please help me!

**Update:**
From the documentation I read that Sprockets "default" is /assets but it certainly isn't in my application. I use the latest version of rails. Can the documentation be outdated?
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Even if I add `config.assets.prefix = "/assets"` to my production it would still mean that I would not load the assets since the digest would be missing.

Comment: Did you run production env with `rails s` or with external web server?

Comment: External I use nginx, I did some changes and used the rake task to build assets and suddently it just worked and the urls changed. Weird, I am not sure what fixed it. :p

Comment: It seems you had to restart your rails server after assets are recompiled. Production enviroment, you know, it should be restarted after any trifle :) I could reproduse your situation if I run production server without assets compiled, recompile assets, and refresh the web page without restarting the server.

Comment: Yeah that was probably it. I first ran rake assets:precompile but that didn't work and I had to run bunle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production.

But thanks for your help any way :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the same problem I was experiencing. Instead of using `url()`in your css (or scss), use `asset-data-url()` and add `config.assets.enabled = true` to your application config file. Then, `rake assets:precompile` before you push.